# How to pre-compile jsp tag files?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tags, jsp-tags

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html says:

> Tag files can also be compiled into
>   Java classes and bundled as a tag
>   library. This is useful when you wish
>   to distribute a binary version of the
>   tag library without the original
>   source. If you choose this form of
>   packaging, you must use a tool that
>   produces portable JSP code that uses
>   only standard APIs.

How can i pre-compile them? I tried jspc but it failed :

> BUILD FAILED
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   ... link.tagx(8,40) directive.attribute
>   action can be used in tag files only

Comment: What application server is this running on?

Comment: jetty in development modus, tomcat for production

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://javapapers.com/jsp/how-to-pre-compile-jsp/). I think pre-compiling JSPs also pre-compiles the TAG libraries referenced.

Comment: But i dont have JSPs in my project, just tagfiles i want to use in another project.

Comment: Theres an ant task available as Jasper2 that can precompile tag files. See if that helps you out.

Comment: hmm i did not find anything about this task here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html Can you give me a link?