# Do tags written in Java (i.e., extending BodyTagSupport or TagSupport) perform better than .tag files?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, taglib

At work some developers are changing `.tag` files into tags that are written in Java. The reason was performance. They stated that there was a ten-fold increase in performance when comparing `.tag` files and those written in Java. The evidence was empirical.

I'm trying to find some factual data to back this up, but couldn't find any performance comparisons online. I did find documentation that talked about tag pooling and how that can improve performance, but I couldn't find anything comparing the two.

Comment: probably request them to prove what they claimed?

Comment: @Jasonw They did prove it. I saw the differences in performance. But it was purely empirical. We already precompile our JSP's so the .tag files should be compiled as well. I wonder if tag pooling might be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .tag files are supposed to be compiled to java code on first access. So you might have a performance hit just on the first access, afterwards it's supposed to be the same.

You can avoid that by pre-compiling them. The way to setup the pre-compilation varies between servers (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822710/how-to-pre-compile-jsp-tag-files) for example)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, JSP tags (`.tag`) might cause a performance hit initially, but once executed it should work as fast as a Java based custom tag. Because, JSP tags (`.tag`) works similar to `JSP`s.